# How to parse a string like 20170202 to a date in a bash script?

Tags: filenames, date

Say I have several files that are generated by a script and follow the pattern:

`yyyymmdd_fileName.fileExtension`

And yyyymmdd (i.e. 20170202) is a date, where year is 2017, month is February and day is the 2nd).

I know I can get the complete file name and extract the date part, but how do I make it a date element so I can compare with the current date provided by `date`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-d` arg of `date`.

`man date`

> ```
>    -d, --date=STRING
>           display time described by STRING, not 'now'
> ```

```
$ date -d 20170202
Thu Feb  2 00:00:00 CET 2017
```

To ease the comparsion, you can use the unixdate format

```
$ date -d 20170203 +%s
1486076400
```

Comment: `-d` is specific to GNU `date`; on BSD `date` it sets the kernel's value for daylight saving time.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `touch`. This should work on most systems, but you need to specify time as `hhmm.ss`. I normally use `1200.00`.

```
touch -t 201702021200.00
```